# Hackerrank Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps solution in C++

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, hash-map

This is a solution for the Day 8 hackerrank.com challenge. The basic idea of the challenge is to create a mapping of names to phone numbers based on the the given input, and later look up the phone numbers for certain names. If the entry exists, print it and its number. If it doesn't, print out "Not found".

Here's my solution in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, n;
    cin>>n;
    string name, number, key;
    map<string, string> phone_dir;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>name>>number;
        phone_dir.insert(pair <string, string> (name, number));
    }
    while(cin>>key)
    {
        if (phone_dir.find(key) != phone_dir.end())
        {
             cout<<key<<"="<<phone_dir.find(key)->second<< endl;
        }
        else cout<< "Not found"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Is there a more efficient solution in C++ for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should not use `using namespace std;` This is bad practice that will get you into trouble once you want to use a function that has the same name.
2. You can use descriptive names. So instead of "n" use "numEntries" or whatever.
3. You should declare the iteration variable inside the for loop rather than at the beginning.
4. `std::map` has an `emplace` method that you should use rather than insert.
5. You are using a `std::map`, which is is a red black tree. You most likely want a `std::unordered_map`
6. You search twice for the key. With modern C++17 you can do the following:

   ```
   if (auto res = phone_dir.find(key); res != phone_dir.end())
   {
        std::cout << key << "=" << res->second << std::endl;
   } else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
   }
   ```
7. You are using `std::endl` which involves a flush of the stream. You definitely only want a `\n` here.
8. Whitespace is cheap. Grab some to improve readability
9. Same for lines. It is bad practice to have braces on one condition and pu the other one on the same line. This severely affects readability
10. `return 0;` is implied for main so you can skip that.
11. I almost forgot, you should reserve the space in the map.

Comment: For #6, did you mean `if ((auto res = phone_dir.find(key)) != phone_dir.end())`?

Comment: @MikeBorkland Most people would consider that too tight - just write "auto res = ...; if (res != phone_dir.end()) { ... } You just want to avoid two calls to find(). On the other hand, that's only because you asked "is there a more efficient solution". The printing will take a lot longer than the finding, so your code is not too bad.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's not my code...

Comment: @MikeBorkland ??? "For #6, did you mean..." followed presumably by your code, and followed by your name.

Comment: I'm not a fan of implicitly depending on the tie feature between `cin` and `cout`, since it doesn't mean exactly what most people think it does.

Comment: @MikeBorkland I meant the new C++17 feature, that allows declaration of variables in if/switch statements before the condition.

Comment: @gnasher729 If you read your comment again, perhaps you will see why I thought you had somehow confused me with the OP.

Comment: @miscco I wasn't aware of that new feature! Good to know, thanks.